# How to edit integers of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I’m trying to take a list like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 8, 15, 4, 12, 8]
```

And whenever a number is larger than 9 or has two digits, that number has 10 subtracted from it, and 1 is added to the previous number in the list.

So the list would result into this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 5, 2, 8]
```

For now, i have something like:

```
for i in list:
    If i in list>= 10
        list[i] = list[i] - 10
        list[i-1] = list[i-1] + 1
```

But I’m getting an error from this

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you do this by writing the logic for it.

Comment: @raphaelm22 - please show the code you have tried. Take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are enumerating the list and as your logic says, if we encounter a number that is bigger than 9, we substract it from 10 and we add 1 to the previous element.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 8, 15, 4, 12, 8]
for index,item in enumerate(my_list):
    if item > 9:
        my_list[index] -= 10
        if index > 0:
            my_list[index-1] += 1

print(my_list) # [1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 5, 2, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data =  [1, 2, 3, 8, 15, 4, 12, 8]

count = 0
for item in data:
    if item >= 10 :
        data[count-1] += 1
        data[count] -= 10
    count += 1
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 5, 2, 8]
```

Comment: `data =  [11, 2, 3, 8, 15, 4, 12, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is man, but this only handles if the first item is less than 10 because I did not make the logic for it to check if its the first item, it will crash if the first item in the list is greater than or equal to 10.

```
x = [1,2,3,8,15,4,12,8]

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    if x[i] >= 10:
        x[i] = x[i]-10
        x[i-1] = x[i-1]+1


print(x)
```

the output will be

```
[1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 5, 2, 8]
```

Comment: This is a simple solution and I suggest in the future just to add a bit more detail to your question, for example ideas you have tried, thoughts, errors, etc so you get a great answer